# Compacting table in FME?

Tags: fme-form

How to compact table using FME which table has grouped by CODE and different value of class are as columns?

Before

[image: table before]

After

[image: table after]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest part is to use an Aggregator transformer, with the Group-By set to CODE.

[image]

Then you'll get two features, as shown in the After table.

The question then is, how do we handle the attributes? I would drop existing attributes and create a list:

[image]

Now we need to move those list elements into attributes. There are various ways to do this. From your limited data, I see two classes, 5 and 9. So I would just use an AttributeCreator:

[image]

The idea is that you're creating an attribute whose name incorporates the class value and whose value is the area:

[image]

So that's more or less complete. I'm assuming you only have 2 classes (5 and 9) and that the data is sorted in that order (5 first, then 9). I can't tell what your end requirements are, so you might also want to use an AttributeExposer to expose the new attributes, and you might want to change Aggregation Mode to "Attributes Only".

If you do have multiple classes, then the list creation part will work, but the attribute creation part would need adjusting. If there is a variable number of classes per code, you could add a custom transformer with a loop to loop through the list fetching each class in turn. There are examples in the [FME Community knowledgebase](https://community.safe.com) that would show you how to use that.

You also might find the ListBreaker transformer (from the FME Hub) useful too.